# How to find the actively debugged call frame using visual studio API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

Using Visual studio's IVsDebugger API I can get hold of events related to debugging.

This passes me events with a DebugEngine, a DebugProcess, a DebugProgram and a DebugThread.

Using these interfaces I can find a list of frames on each thread, but nothing to do with the active frame (the frame the user has double clicked on in the Call Stack to inspect).

Is it possible to find which frame in the callstack is currently being debugged?

Visual studio have docs for extending their editor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx but don't go into detail about the Call Stack window.

Comment: Doubtful, it is a feature of the Call Stack window, not the debugger.  Which surely doesn't do anything more than call IVSDebugger2::ShowSource().

Comment: But both the Locals and Watch window are relative to the active call stack location, so Visual Studio must pass this data around somewhere (even if its internal)

Comment: Anyone? Where / how is the information about which stack frame is currently selected stored?

Comment: With DTE it is really simple: ((EnvDTE80.DTE2)GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE))).Debugger.CurrentStackFrame - so there must be a way to do it with IVSDebugger, too. The 'Remarks'-section of IDebugThread2 should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145332.aspx

Comment: After some more research: the first half of this blog-post should help to solve the problem:
https://macropolygon.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/evaluating-debugged-process-memory-in-a-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: And make sure to read my comment below the above mentioned blog post: IDebuggerInternal has an CurrentStackFrame-member that returns IDebugStackFrame2!